# How to integrate with mysql in google checkout?

Tags: mysql, database, integration, google-checkout

I am working on Google checkout to sell my product online. i want order information to be stored in `mysql` database on my server only after payment verification of customer.when customer click on order now button on Google checkout synchronously that order complete information to be stored in database also. i m in fix to solve this but not getting any way of out..

Comment: What's the issue? Where are you stuck?

Comment: how can i send the order details to my server for storing them when user click Buy Now button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that the order is not complete when the customer clicks the Buy Now button. The order is complete after the customer finishes the order on Google Checkout's "Place Order" page and Google verifies and charges the credit card.

To get order processing details use the Google Checkout Notification API:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Notification_API.html

You'll get callbacks at various order processing stages which will allow you to update your database and inventory accordingly.